# Using sed, how can I append "START" above the first line and "END" below the last line?

Tags: linux

Using sed, how can I append "START" above the first line and "END" below the last line?

Input file:

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300

Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500

Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400

Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245700

Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900

Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use "addresses": `1` stand for the first line, `^` means the beginning of the line. `$` stands for the last line in an address, and also means end-of-line in a regular expression.

```
sed -e '1s/^/START\n/' -e '$s/$/\nEND/'
```

Comment: @Steve, if choroba's answer answers your question please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without matching using i and a commands.

```
sed -e '1i START' -e '$a END'
```

but it comes to the same thing.